# SUMIF, INDEX, MATCH Multiple Columns and Rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on some non-profit work and can't figure out how to sum a table based on two criteria:

1. Is it donated (Column)
2. Is it in the DR (Row)

Here is a simplified version of my table:

[image]

The equation I'm using so far is:

```
=sumif(A2:A6,B11,index(B2:F6,0,match(C10,B1:F1,0)))
```

The MATCH function only finds the first row with DR and sums everything. Is there a way to take it one step further to sum all of the columns and rows?

I'm also using Google Sheets and not Excel.

I would greatly appreciate any help, as I've been stuck on this forever.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should work in Excel or Google Sheets

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:E6*(A2:A6=B11)*(B1:E1=C10))
```

Answer (score 2):

[google-spreadhseet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadhseet)

`=sum(filter(b2:f6 , a2:a6 = b11 , b1:f1 = c10))`

> **Thanks to I'-'I:** You need to use double FILTER. `=sum(filter(FILTER(b2:f6 , a2:a6 = b11) , b1:f1 = c10))`

also try:

`=ArrayFormula(sum(B2:F6 * --(A2:A6 = B11) * --(B1:F1 = C10)))`

Comment: Hello Max, I've inputted that formula, but it comes back with the error: FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 5. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.